# Asumption of normality for two-way repeated measures ANOVA not met?

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, normality-assumption

I have tested my data for a normal distribution (using a histogram on R studio) but the data were not normally distributed. I tried a sqrt, log and asin transformation on the dependent variable but this did not solve the issue. Would anyone be able to advise me on how to proceed?

:)

Comment: Testing a repeated measures two-way ANOVA for normality using a histogram is likely to be difficult.  Note that normality of your outcome variable is not required but normality of the errors (difference from group means).  Repeated measures also adds complexity!  Can you give more information about your study design and what exactly you tested?

Comment: @GeorgeSavva We looked at the human ability to path integrate, where humans had to navigate through a virtual corridor to a pre-seen target location. The dependent variable was the absolute error (difference between the actual target location and subjects stop location). The distance from the start of the corridor to the target was one of five different distances and thus target distance was a within-subjects independent variable. The gain (difference in velocity from trial-to-trial) also differed between sessions (3 sessions with 50 trials each). Thus, gain and distance were independent vs :)

Comment: @GeorgeSavva please see my recent post about how to check the assumption of normality for two-way repeated measures ANOVA

Comment: Can you share (a link to) the data, or at least some plots or model output?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Hello! I realised I was incorrectly plotting the qqplot, I thus decided to use the aov function instead since this gave me the residuals which I could then plot. However aov assumes the sphericity assumption is met and so I am now going to use a linear mixed effects model :)